# Center span with text in div

Tags: html, css

this is some rotating text I have:

```
<div class="abc"">
</br></br>
  <h2 class="sentence" >We Are  

 <br class="rwd-break">
    <div class="slidingHorizontal">
  <span style="color: #3cae75;">  Effective <img src="../21.png" style="display:inline;" ></span> 
  <span style="color: #ce9f13;">  Exclusive <img src="../11.png" style="display:inline;" ></span> 
  <span style="color: #e31620;">  Exciting <img src="../41.png" style="display:inline;" ></span>
  <span style="color: #ffffff;">  The next big thing in town! <img src="../31.png" style="display:inline;" ></span>
</div>
```

The 'We Are' part remains static while the text in the 4 spans alternate every 4 seconds. Heres the link to the code I used to rotate the text: http://codepen.io/Ignet/pen/zGKgmq

Now I want to center the *rendered* text on the screen.

The 'We are' part is being centered but the spans are not. 
Heres the css im using:

```
.abc{
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
/*  margin: auto auto;
 text-align: center;*/
  font-family: hobo std;
  position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,0);
}

/* alternate text */
/*Sentence*/

.sentence {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-family: hobo std;
 text-align: center;}
```

And I need it to be responsive too. Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
.wrapper>h2{text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `display: inline;` for `.slidingHorizontal` and remove the `<br class="rwd-break">`. This will make the `span` aligned next to the text `We are` and center align the text. I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: didn't work :( I need the text to be centered relative to what is being rendered from the span, for example, if the screen shows 'we are effective' it will be centered somewhere around the ff in effective, if it shows 'we are the next big thing in town' it will be centered around 'big'.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with all your issues?

Answer (score 0):

I already adjust the way you wanted.

On your

HTML

```
<body>
<header>

</header>
<section class="wrapper">

  <h2 class="sentence">We Are
    <div class="slidingHorizontal">
      <span style="color: #3cae75;">Effective <img src="../21.png" style="display:inline;" ></span>
      <span style="color: #ce9f13;">Exclusive <img src="../21.png" style="display:inline;" ></span>
      <span style="color: #e31620;">Exciting <img src="../21.png" style="display:inline;" ></span>
      <span style="color: #ffffff;">The next big thing in town! <img src="../21.png" style="display:inline;" ></span>
    </div>
  </h2>


  </section>

</body>
```

CSS

```
/*Body*/

body {
  background-color: #00abe9;
}
/*Sentence*/

.sentence {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
/*Wrapper*/

.wrapper {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #00abe9;
}
/* Horizontal alternate text */
/*Horizontal Sliding*/

.slidingHorizontal {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 8px;
}

.slidingHorizontal span {
  animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #00abe9;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}
/*leftToRight Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes leftToRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes leftToRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes leftToRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
/* end alternate text horizontal */
```

Remind to yourself be careful with CSS: position: absolute; :)

Here the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doxpea?editors=110)

*its responsive too

*Hoping that you learn something. Best of luck to you.

Comment: nope, this is giving me the exact same result as before; I need something that looks like this: http://www.nitrografix.net/ where the 'we are' moves horizontally relative to the spans