# How to center a span in a div

Tags: html, css

i have already tried many thing to center a span Element (which contains couple of DIVs) in a wrapper DIV (in this case the soccerField DIV)...

HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div id="soccerField">
    <span id="defendLine">
        <div>player 1</div>
        <div>player 2</div>
        <div>player 3</div>
        <div>player 4</div>
    </span>
<div>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
#field{
padding: 0%;
min-width: 250px;
min-height: 1000px;
max-width: 800px;
position: relative;
text-align: center
}

#defendLine{
 display: inline-block;  
}
```

at the moment it looks like:
[image]

at the end it should looks like:
[image]

but this result i only get when I am using this code:

```
#defendLine{
  position: absolute;
  left:59px
}
```

but this is not the right way I think becasue when I have only 3 players or 5 players at my DefendLine, i also have to give some "left: X" values. But i want to make it dynamically. >> doesnt matter how much players, always center the span element, independentley how much players my  includes.

I have already check these articles which helps other, but in this case. I couldnt help myself :(

[CSS How to center a div horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821277/css-how-to-center-a-div-horizontally)
[How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

I would be really happy if anyone could give me a hint!

Edit:

I have created a fiddle, i tried all solutions out. I think something else is the reason for my problem :(

https://jsfiddle.net/rztad75y/2/

Comment: on a separate consideration.. you may benefit from embedding resources.. jump over to https://www.base64-image.de/ .. drag and drop your images.. get the css declaration that contains the image/base64 string representation..

Comment: you have a lot more style declarations going on there.. seems you're inheriting `margin:0` from a style declaration toward the bottom.. it should be `margin:0 auto` on `#defendLine`.. as @Eli indicated in his answer. and really..that's the only consideration here. `text-align:center;` on parent and `margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto` on child

Comment: ok i wil try it again now, hold on pls

Comment: @BrettCaswell: i did exactly what you said ;) look here please at the CSS section i have placed the relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/rztad75y/7/
but like you see in the fiddle, it doesn't work...

Comment: yeah.. I did..the issue is you're assign `position:absolute; left; top;` on `.def`

https://jsfiddle.net/rztad75y/9/

Comment: check this please: https://jsfiddle.net/UsulPro/rztad75y/8/ is it what you need?

Comment: @OlegPro WOW OLEG! THANKS THATS REALLY WHAT I NEED!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center span with text in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176703/center-span-with-text-in-div)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/UsulPro/rztad75y/8/) with the solution and I'll explain some keys of how to achieve it:

1) I use `flexbox`

```
#field {
  /* I skip properties that do not change */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* here we just put the only child div to the center */
}
```

I changed `#defendLine` to `.defendLineSE` just to make sure that it's not overriden elsewhere. (that's why your code could not work - just change that back)

```
.defendLineSE {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

2) Note that we need to **have** width. This width is a sum of `#defendie`-s width and spaces between them (`justify-content: space-between;`)

3) I removed all `position: absolute` in your `#defendie` because they destroy our flexbox (you don't need to use `left: 387px;` as well)

tip1: I believe you will find usefull this [flexbox-cheatsheet](http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/)

tip2: Since we use `justify-content: space-between;` you may not need such classes like `.firstColumn` and others

tip3: change `#defendLine` to `.anyLine`, remove `width: 400px;`, add `margin` to your `.defendie`-s - you'll have universal solution for any line with any number of players

Comment: hey Oleg, for some reasons bothe of your solutions aer not working...
I think something else is wrong... I have added a fiddle at my 1st post (sorry for the huge css part)... maybe its easier to see where the problem is... thank you also to you for your help! ;)

Comment: Could you checked: https://jsfiddle.net/UsulPro/rztad75y/8/ Is it what you are looking for? It's in the middle. I was need to remove some `absolute` props in CSS. If you like it, I can give you some details about solution

Comment: thank you so much man! yes pleas! could you tell me what i have to change?

Comment: can i copy the whole css part back into my own code? EDIT: no it doesnt work that easy hehe... I tried it without success

Comment: @nbg15 that depends on your application and configuration.. it looks like there is possible bundling going on there.. and potential for transpiling..

Answer (score 6):

using a `<span>` tag is a bad practice. instead, change it to a `<div>` like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="soccerField">
    <div id="defendLine">
        <div>player 1</div>
        <div>player 2</div>
        <div>player 3</div>
        <div>player 4</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
#defendLine{
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;  
}
```

**Edit**
if you'd like to center the content of the div itself, set `text-align:center` or simply use flexbox:

```
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

more info could be found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hey Eli! Thanks for your help! your first comment doesnt work. and about your edited answer I have one question! Should I add these 3 lines to my wrapper div or to my child div (old span)??? Thank u so much! greetings

Comment: if you'll check the guide you'll see that flexbox is always added to the container of your elements :) anyway, <span>s are for text elements so stick to divs. and check the link i've gave you

Comment: please accept the answer if it's correct. thank you @nbg15

Comment: Thanks for your help again Eli, but your code doenst helped me out :( 
MAybe you could check my fiddle at my 1st post? I really dont know what other css is the reason why your code doenst work for me :(

Comment: they wont change because you gave them `position: absolute`. if you're not familiar with grid solutions, try using some framework for it (i recommend Zurb's Foundation) and learn to work with columns @nbg15

Comment: I put a quick fix in the handle his code in https://jsfiddle.net/rztad75y/9/ .. but you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Using a `<span>` is NOT bad practice unless you are saying it's bad practice in this case but that would be subject to opinion. I don't see how using a `<div>` changes anything.

Comment: @Rob using `span` as a container for other elements is a bad practice.. the same goes for `p`.. those tags are only supposed to contain text.. it also breaks accessibility readers/interpreters.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Yes. I was basing my comment on what he said and his suggested solution but didn't relate it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `transform: translateX()` like this..

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

```css
#field{
padding: 0;
min-width: 250px;
min-height: 1000px;
max-width: 800px;
position: relative;
text-align: center
}

#defendLine{
 display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

}
#defendLine div {
 display: flex;
 flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="soccerField">
    <span id="defendLine">
        <div>player 1</div>
        <div>player 2</div>
        <div>player 3</div>
        <div>player 4</div>
    </span>
<div>
```

It works vertically as well..

```
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Hey Hastig Zusammenstellen! Thanks for your help! Your code always center it. Thats good ;) but out of my player field! (center it depends on the whole width size of my page if have the feelings)... i cant add images to this post here I think!

Comment: If you can recreate it in a fiddle we can help you with that. You may need to put `width: 100%;` on your `img` so that it's responsive relative to its container.

Answer (score 1):

Use **display: flex** for the parent div, and **justify-content: center** to center items inside on the horizontal axis, and **align-items: center** to center them vertically.
Flex boxes are a real helper in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. You can center elements using [text-align: center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

```css
#field{
padding: 0%;
min-width: 250px;
min-height: 1000px;
max-width: 800px;
position: relative;
/*text-align: center*/
}

#defendLine{
 text-align: center;
 display: block;/* This is a span, you have to make it a block*/
}

#defendLine div{
 display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
<div id="soccerField">
    <span id="defendLine">
        <div>player 1</div>
        <div>player 2</div>
        <div>player 3</div>
        <div>player 4</div>
    </span>
<div>
```